# SQL Server : group by a function on a field an select that

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, aggregation

I have a `group by YEAR(mydate),MONTH(mydate)`

I want to select them as a unique field like

```
SELECT SUM(Price),YEAR(mydate) + '/' + MONTH(mydate)
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY YEAR(mydate), MONTH(mydate)
```

or something like this.

`mydate` is `smalldatetime`.

Is it possible?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do - does this query work? Or if not: in what way does it not work as you want it to??

Comment: i wanna know sum(price) per year/month

Comment: OK - but doesn't that query already answer that question?

Comment: i got errors because mydate is not mentioned in group-by list

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT cast(YEAR(mydate) as CHAR(4))+'/'+cast(MONTH(mydate) as varchar(2))
FROM MyTable
Group by YEAR(mydate),MONTH(mydate)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert them to strings

Try

```
SELECT convert(varchar(7), mydate ,111)
FROM MyTable 
GROUP BY convert(varchar(7), mydate ,111)
```

Comment: i got errors because mydate is not mentioned in group-by list

Answer (score 0):

For MS SQL Server 2012, with leading zeros:

```
CAST(YEAR(mydate) AS VARCHAR(4)) + '/' +
RIGHT('00' + CAST(MONTH(mydate) AS VARCHAR(2)), 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

here my solution :)
I need to get older date in a sqlserver table (columns year_rif  and month_rif) to insert newer record from a linked oracle table (to mirroring oracle table in sqlserver by monthly job)

```
DECLARE @anno_INIZIO int
DECLARE @mese_INIZIO int

select top(1) @mese_INIZIO= mese_rif,@anno_INIZIO=anno_rif 
 from dbo.ORACLE_BUDGET_MENSILI 
 group by  mese_rif,anno_rif 
 order by max(mese_rif/12+anno_rif) desc

set @anno_inizio=coalesce(@anno_INIZIO ,2016)
set @mese_INIZIO=coalesce(@mese_INIZIO,1)
```

At first import I assume start get data from january 2016
The full job is:

```
    DECLARE @anno_INIZIO int
    DECLARE @mese_INIZIO int
--get max year/mont avaible in mirrored table
    select top(1) @mese_INIZIO= mese_rif,@anno_INIZIO=anno_rif from dbo.ORACLE_BUDGET_MENSILI group by  mese_rif,anno_rif order by max(mese_rif/12+anno_rif) desc
--
    set @anno_inizio=coalesce(@anno_inizio,2016)
    set @mese_INIZIO=coalesce(@mese_INIZIO,1)
-- query to linked oracle to get into table newer data
    SET @SQL='select * FROM OPENQUERY(ADL_REP,''
    SELECT CODICE_UO,ANNO_RIF,MESE_RIF,ID_CLASSE,BUDGET,ORE_MENSILI_OBIETTIVO FROM ADL.BUDGET_MENSILI where  mese_rif/12+anno_rif > '+convert(varchar(255),@mese_INIZIO/12+@anno_INIZIO)+'
    '')'
    INSERT INTO uat.[dbo].ORACLE_BUDGET_MENSILI EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT CAST(DATENAME(yy, mydate) AS CHAR(4)) + '-' + CAST(DATENAME(mm, mydate) AS VARCHAR(2)) 'Date'
 ,SUM(Price)
FROM [My Table]
GROUP BY DATENAME(yy, mydate)
 ,DATENAME(ww, mydate)
```

Comment: Please provide the explanation for the the answers as well.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional [context](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now! Please [edit] your answer to add an explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. It also doesn't hurt to mention why this answer is more appropriate than others.